# Is it possible to accept multiple (> 2) calls through CallKit's "Accept and Hold" button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, voip, callkit

I have implemented CallKit for a VoIP app. The "accept and hold" behaviour works well: the active call is put on hold and the new call is accepted.

But when I have one call active, one call on hold already and another call comes in, CallKit only gives me the option to terminate the held call and accept the new call.

Is this behaviour expected? Does CallKit only support one held call at least for incoming calls or am I missing something?

Comment: if thats the option it gives you then it must only support two calls at a time

Comment: Have you already tried to change the value of `maximumCallGroups` or `maximumCallsPerCallGroup` of the `CXProviderConfiguration`? The default value of `maximumCallGroups` is suspiciously 2.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try to set it to a higher number (5 for testing purposes) but it still behaves as before.